# Codeigniter email on works sometimes

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

Hi my website doesn't seem to accept emails when it comes from particular email addresses.  Why is that?  I am using code igniter 2.1. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; 


$this->email->initialize($config);  

 $a=$this->load->view('cart/email',$data,true);
$this->email->from($data['email'], $data['fname'].' '.$data['lname']);
$this->email->to('order@abc.ca'); 
$this->email->subject('Your Order');
$this->email->message($a);  
$this->email->send();
  echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

THe result from the debugger says "Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail"

This is on public linux server (not localhost)

Comment: Do these providers accept HTML mailtype ?

Comment: look at the email destination to see if the message isn´t in the spam folder

Comment: Yes they do accept HTML mail type